# How can I define type in gql query in Apollo Client?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

My Apollo Server have following definition.

```
input MinMax{
  min:Float
  max:Float
}
input ScreenerInput{
  fy:Int!
  quarter:Int!
  ltp:MinMax
  eps:MinMax
  pe:MinMax
  netWorth:MinMax
  paidUp:MinMax
  reserve:MinMax
  netProfit:MinMax
}
```

How can I define `MinMax` type in Apollo client to send variables for the `MinMax` type. Till now I was doing scalar types only so my query were simple.

My query type is `screeenedCompanies(criteria:ScreenerInput!):[ScreenedCompanies]`

if I query directly like below it works.

```
{
  screeenedCompanies(criteria:{
    fy:2075
    quarter:2
    eps:{
      min:30
      max:40
    }
  }){
    sector
    symbol
  }
}
```

What I want is to query like this so that variables can be changed

```
query getScreenedCompanies($criteria:<What type should be here ?>){  

{
  screeenedCompanies(criteria:$criteria){
    sector
    symbol
  }
}
}
```

After giving `ScreenerInput` as type my query looks like below

```
query getScreenedCompanies($criteria:ScreenerInput!){  
  screeenedCompanies(criteria:$criteria){
    sector
    symbol
  }
}
```

my variables in apolloplayground look like below

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "fy": 2075
    "quarter": 4
    "ltp": {
      "min": 345
      "max": 400
    }
  }
}
```

I am receiving the following error

```
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Variable \"$criteria\" of required type \"ScreenerInput!\" was not provided."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way, as any scalar type in `GQL`. Just define them with the same input name as on the server(like `MinMax` or `ScreenerInput` in your case). You don't need to describe its shape on the client, server will validate it for you :)

And don't forget to add exclamation mark `!`, if parameter is required.

Comment: Hi Thank your for your answer. But I still cannot get it to working. My  `query` type is `screeenedCompanies(criteria:ScreenerInput!):[ScreenedCompanies]`. How do I query this from apollo client.`MinMax` is my case is not a required field so no `!` mark.

Comment: _But I still cannot get it to working_ what errors have you got and what query are you using? You can update your question to reflect that

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have edited the question. Can you please check.

Comment: I see. So, what error do you see specifically? In the query you need to use the same input type as on the server: `ScreenerInput!`

Comment: Thanks. Now I think I am close to making it right but still getting the above error. I have edited the question. Can you please check.

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. I might assume you've selected `HTTP Headers` tab rather than `Query variables`, check if you're on the right one. If so, add a screenshot of your apolloplayground to your question

Comment: Hi, I was missing commas on the `query variables`. Now it is working fine. Thanks a lot for helping out